# C# macro application

Tags: c#, winforms, macros, sendkeys, keystroke

I'm trying to create a winform C# application, which will send keystrokes to a program, acting like a macro application (sending keystrokes). 
I am using Windows Input Simulator. *https://inputsimulator.codeplex.com/*

The problem is that it can only send keystrokes to a program with admin right, if the application I created also runs with admin rights. The only way I've found to run a *.application* file is by using CMD, which is a headache, any other ways to do it?

Second it does not seem to work with all programs. I have trouble trying to send keystrokes to *Avid - Pro Tools*. Maybe there is another method of sending keystrokes?

I can easily achieve macros with my *Logitech* mouse, why can't I do that with programming? Am I missing something?

Here's to focus an application code:

```
protected override CreateParams CreateParams
    {
        get
        {
            CreateParams param = base.CreateParams;
            param.ExStyle |= 0x08000000;
            return param;
        }
    }
```

And a sample send code:

```
private void audioTrack_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        InputSimulator.SimulateModifiedKeyStroke(
           new[] { VirtualKeyCode.CONTROL, VirtualKeyCode.SHIFT },
           new[] { VirtualKeyCode.VK_N });

        InputSimulator.SimulateKeyDown(VirtualKeyCode.RETURN);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like SendKeys.Send is the way to go! Don't know why I bothered to use Windows Input Simulator library... With SendKeys.Send it works perfectly, no need for admin rights and much less code.